# Redirect from featured questions, when there are no featured questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Today I visited CR for the first time in a while to do a CR on my lunch break. Hit my favoured language (C#) and was greeted by this:

[image]

Instead of pointing us to a different tab, wouldn't it be better to just see the list of questions when there are no featured questions? I personally think that it would result in a better user experience.

Thoughts?

Comment: I totally agree, the same goes for the "unanswered" tab.

Comment: I think that that would be very confusing. If I don't pay attention, I might think that all the questions are featured. And if I do pay attention, I would think that there is something wrong with the site. Why does it take me to the list of questions when I wanted to see featured questions? I think this would result in a lot of "it doesn't work" questions here. Maybe if you add a popup notification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you go to any of the main tabs, like 'info', 'newest', 'active', etc. and then go to any other tag, etc, it will *stay on the same tab*.... So, for example, if you [go to the Java 'newest' page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing+java?sort=newest), there are the newest [java](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java) questions. If you click on any other tags on that page, it will go to the 'newest' tab of that other tag.

If you click on a question, and then click on the main 'Questions' page, it will come back to all-tags ***newest*** page. It remembers where you have been, and assumes that that is where you want to hang out, unless you tell it otherwise. This consistent behaviour is .... good.

This is true for all the tabs except the 'info' tab. That tab is not remembered.

So, if you are on the [featured tab for ... Python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python?sort=featured) (there currently are some featured Python questions....), then the system will store 'featured' as your last tab. If you click on another tag (something that is not on the bountied questions), you will go to that tags' featured tab as well (or [after going here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=featured) click here [cobol](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cobol)). Now, on that COBOL page, go to 'newest' (and napalm the questions ... ;-) and you will see there is no 'featured' tab at all.

The system knows when there are no 'featured' tabs, and it will not show you, or go there, unless the 'featured' tab was the last place you went.

Comment: I would add that sometime questions are masked by an ignored tags. So if you visit the featured tab with an ignored question what would have been the expected result ? I think what we actually have is predictable and easy to navigate (so +1)!

Comment: Hmmm, I see why this behaviour is. It just caught me off guard because I was expecting to see all questions tagged C# after clicking the C# tag.